# How to create instance of javascript function without using arguments

Tags: javascript, callback

I am using a JavaScript API of some software. In software there are Solutions and they contain Worklists.

For each Solution I want to list Worklists.

```
solutions = obtainSolutionsformAPI();
for (i=0,i<solutions.length,i++){
    sol=solutions[i];
    sol.obtainWorklists(callbackFunction);    
}
```

the callbackFunction is called by software and the array of worklists is passed as the argument.

```
function callbackFunction(arrayOfWorkLists){
    for (j=0,j<arrayOfWorkLists.length,j++){
        wl=arrayOfWorkLists[j];
        console.log(wl);
    }
}
```

now in console.log I would like to also print out the `i` variable (the number of solution) together witch each worklist, but how do I get the `i` inside callback function, when I am not the one who is calling it? I suspect I need to modify the callback function each time before I pass it to `sol.obtainWorklists(callbackFunction);` What is the correct way of doing this?

Edit: I do not want the function defintions to be nested (one inside other), because I have multiple nestings like this one and it would be quite unreadable. So I do not want this:

```
sol.obtainWorklists(function callbackFunction(arrayOfWorkLists){...});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a builder function:

```
sol.obtainWorklists(buildCallback(i, callbackFunction));
```

...where `buildCallback` looks like this:

```
function buildCallback(index, func) {
    return function() {
        var args = [index];
        args.push.apply(args, arguments);
        func.apply(this, args);
    };
}
```

**Complete example below**

Then in your callback, expect the `i` value as the first argument with the arguments that `obtainWorklists` normally provides following it.

How that works:

- When you *call* `buildCallback`, you pass in the `i` value and the callback you want called.
- `buildCallback` returns a new function which has that information bound to it (it's a *closure* over the `index` and `func` arguments in the call to `buildCallback`).
- When `obtainWorklists` calls the function `buildCallback` created, we create an array with the `i` value (`index`) followed by the arguments that were received from `obtainWorklists`.
- Then we call the callback, using the same `this` value that the function was called with, and the `args` array; your callback will see the entries in `args` as discrete arguments.

If you don't care about the `this` value in your callback, you can use ES5's `Function#bind` instead:

```
sol.obtainWorklists(callbackFunction.bind(null, i));
```

That does much the same thing, but doesn't preserve the `this` used to call it.

---

Complete example for builder function ([live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/wjJA9/1/)):

```
// obtainWorklists stand-in
function obtainWorklists(func) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Just call it with a random number
        func(rand(100, 200));
    }, rand(100, 500));
}

// Code to get worklists
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    obtainWorklists(buildCallback(i, callback));
}

function buildCallback(index, func) {
    return function() {
        var args = [index];
        args.push.apply(args, arguments);
        func.apply(this, args);
    };
}


// Your callback
function callback(index, value) {
    display("Index is " + index + ", value is " + value);
}

// ========= Utility functions
function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

---

Complete example for `Function#bind` ([live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/wjJA9/)):

```
// obtainWorklists stand-in
function obtainWorklists(func) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Just call it with a random number
        func(rand(100, 200));
    }, rand(100, 500));
}

// Code to get worklists
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    obtainWorklists(callback.bind(null, i));
}

// Your callback
function callback(index, value) {
    display("Index is " + index + ", value is " + value);
}

// ========= Utility functions
function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the `sol.obtainWorklists(callbackFunction.bind(null, i));` but it did not work. It worked, once I removed null from arguments of bind(). But the problem is that the printed `i` for all worklists is the `i=solutions.length -1` since it is all asynchroneous and the printing occurs when `i` is already `i=solutions.length -1`

Comment: @nothinkelse: You need the `null` (or `undefined`) there, and within your callback, use the first argument passed to the function, **not** `i`.

Comment: @nothinkelse: I've added live examples of both ways. If you don't care what `this` is in the callback, `Function#bind` is probably the better way to go (but be sure all of your target environments have it; IE8 doesn't, for instance, it needs a shim).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a closure:

```
solutions = obtainSolutionsformAPI();
for (i=0,i<solutions.length,i++){
    (function(innerI) {
        sol=solutions[innerI];
        sol.obtainWorklists(function(worklists) {
            callbackFunction(worklists, innerI);
        }
    })(i);
}

function callbackFunction(arrayOfWorkLists, i){
    console.log(i);
    for (j=0,j<arrayOfWorkLists.length,j++){
        wl=arrayOfWorkLists[j];
        console.log(wl);
    }
}
```